# I'm new to learning Korean, and I'm really excited, but, I'm not sure where to start. Does anyone have any tips for a newbie like me?

Tags: beginners

I started trying to learn Korean like 2 days ago, but it doesn't make any sense to me at all. I tried learning it because I heard it's super easy to learn. Does anyone have any tips for a beginner like me?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest learning hangul first (the Korean alphabet). Then, I would learn grammar (there are many websites and courses where you can learn it) and then pick up vocabulary along the way :)

Besides that, I think consistent exposure to Korean is important for you to learn how the different grammar points are used.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> I tried learning it because I heard it's super easy to learn.

I can't see in your bio where you're from, but if you're a native English speaker, I don't think any Asian language is going to be super easy to learn... The alphabet is different, the vocabulary has very few similarities to English, the grammar is all different.... If you really find Korean easy, you're a language genius!

For English speakers, I think Korean is very tough compared to learning, say, French or Spanish, which have a lot of similarities in vocabulary with English.

Having said that, the Hangul alphabet is easy to learn, and (as emz says) is an obvious starting point. And if you know English and Hangul, you already know words like 주스 and 비타민.

Also, you say in your bio that you are learning Japanese - and there is a lot of Sino-Korean (Chinese-derived vocabulary) vocabulary that has similar equivalents in Japanese. An example is 만화 - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhwa#History_of_the_term.

I think you'll be disappointed if you expect Learning Korean to be easy, but it is probably something that will go well with learning Japanese. [This article on medium](https://medium.com/story-of-eggbun-education/5-reasons-why-you-should-learn-japanese-and-korean-sequentially-or-simultaneously-cecfe92c8cb3) goes into some more ideas as to why.